# Unhandled Rejection in Google Cloud Functions

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-firestore

I got the following cloud function which works great.
It's listening for an update in the real-time database and update Firestore accordingly.

Everything is fine, except when my user does not exist yet my Firestore database.

This where I need to deal with `Unhandled rejection` that I see in the Google Cloud Functions log.

So see below, in the shortened version of the function, for my `db.collection("users").where("email", "==", email).get()` how to stop the function to move forward and prevent the crash.

```
exports.updateActivities = functions.database.ref("delegates/{userId}/activities").onWrite((event) => {
    //Here I set all the needed variable   
    return rtdb.ref(`delegates/${userId}/email`).once("value", snapshot => {
            //Here I'm fine, email is always present.
        })
        .then(() => {
            db.collection("users").where("email", "==", email).get()

                //This is where I need to handle when there is not matching value, to stop moving forward.

                .then(querySnapshot => {
                    querySnapshot.forEach(val => {
                        console.log("Found match in FireStore " + val.id);
                        firestoreId = val.id;
                    })
                })
                .then(() => {
                    //Here I start my update on Firestore
                });
        })
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use [catch()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/catch) on every promise that you return from your function that could be rejected. This tells Cloud Functions that you handled the error.  The promise returned from catch() will be resolved.

Typically you log the error from catch() so you can see it in the console logs:

```
return somePromise
.then(() => { /* do your stuff */ }
.catch(error => { console.error(error) })
```

Comment: Thanks, so with the `.catch(error => { console.error(error); return })` I also stop the function to continue, or the `return` is optional here?

Comment: You should *always* return a promise from a function that performs async work.

Comment: Doesn't work for me. Even with catch, firebase keeps telling me 'Unhandled error' and totally ignores my catch.

Comment: Same as for @HugoPassos. Can't find the answer on Google docs either.

Answer (score 0):

I used `bluebird` with [`suppressUnhandledRejections`](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/suppressunhandledrejections.html) to get round this issue:

```
import Promise from 'bluebird';

function pool_push(pool, promise)
{
    // In Google Cloud there is a change to crash at `unhandledRejection`.
    // The following trick, basically, tells not to emit
    // `unhandledRejection` since `.catch` will be attached
    // a bit latter.
    const tmp = Promise.resolve(promise);
    tmp.suppressUnhandledRejections();
    pool.items.push(tmp);
}

export default pool_push;
```