# Google Cloud Functions Node.js Error Reporting - Unhandled Rejections not being logged

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-error-reporting

I have a Node.js Cloud Function and am trying to be alerted to unhandled rejections. If I throw an unhandled rejection and cause a crash in my `index.js` entry point, the error shows up in Error Reporting (although I don't receive a notification for some reason). This also shows up as log level "critical":

[image]

If I throw an identical unhandled rejection in a different .js file in the same Cloud Function (which is being imported by `index.js`), it does not show up as log level "critical" and the error is never reported in Error Reporting:

[image]

What is the correct way to ensure I capture all unhandled rejections across my entire Cloud Function (and ensure I receive alerts)? This is how I am initializing Error Reporting in my `index.js` entry point:

```
const {ErrorReporting} = require('@google-cloud/error-reporting');

      const errors = new ErrorReporting({
        reportUnhandledRejections: true
      });
```

Comment: Are you using catch() in your code to tell Cloud Functions that you capture the Unhandled Rejections as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48028366/unhandled-rejection-in-google-cloud-functions)?

Comment: Thanks, it was actually the fact that my error object is instantiated in my index.js but I wasn't passing it to other files within my app, so therefore wasn't being notified. I'll update with my solution.

Comment: If possible, it'd be ideal if you created an answer with the solution you've found :)

Comment: Done, I have answered the question :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got clarification from the Error Reporting team per this github issue: https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-error-reporting/issues/548.

In the end, it was likely because I was only initializing my error reporting object in my main `index.js` and not passing it to or doing so again in my other `.js` files (where the actual unhandled rejections were occurring). One workaround was wrapping my entire `index.js` code in a `try / catch(e)` and in the catch(e) block put in `errors.report(e)`. Then, even if an unhandled rejection occurs in another file during execution, I get notified in Error Reporting.